# gsutil taking 3 hrs to transfer 5000 file from one bucket to another bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil

I am trying to transfer 7000 file from one bucket to another bucket using below command. but it is taking approximately 3 hrs to complete. How to optimize this time within as 5 mins

for ELEMENT in $list; do
gsutil -m mv -r gs://${FILE_PATH}/$ELEMENT gs://${GCS_STORAGE_PATH}/
done

Comment: I think you're not actually parallelizing the `mv`. You're sending each `${ELEMENT}` to `gsutil -m mv` in turn which means the command only uploads a single file and blocks while doing so. When that file is `mv`'d, the next file is started. To use `gsutil -m` correctly, I think you need to pass the command a wildcard that represents the set of files to e.g. `mv` in parallel.

Comment: If you're unable to provide `gsutil` with a pattern to match the set of files, another option, though you'll want to try to limit the number of tasks and it will be trickier to capture each `gsutil` stdout|stderr, is to background (`&`) each gsutil command.

Comment: @DazWilkin - Post that as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @DaxWilkin Can you please provide example command for parallelizing

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not actually parallelizing the `gsutil mv`; well, you are but only for one file (not many).

You're sending each `${ELEMENT}` to `gsutil -m mv` in turn which means the command only uploads a single file and blocks while doing so.

Once each file is `mv`'d, the next file is processed.

To use `gsutil -m` correctly, I think you need to pass the command a wildcard that represents the set of files to e.g. `mv` in parallel.

If you're unable to provide `gsutil` with a pattern to match the set of files (and thus have it parallelize the command), another option, though you'll want to try to limit the number of tasks and it will be trickier to capture the `stdout`|`stderr` from `gsutil`, is to background (`&`) each `gsutil` command.